# In Java, how do I find the time since the last mouse moved?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, mousemotionevent

Say, for example, if I have a circle drawn in a JFrame, and I want to paint over it if I hover over it for three seconds.

I've got a MouseMotionListener that tells me the point of the cursor in the JFrame, but so far that's about it.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
  PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
  cursorPos = a.getLocation();
  SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(cursorPos, e.getComponent());
}
```

I'm still quite new to action listeners. What should I add if I want to test if the mouse is *not* moving?

Also, I'm just curious, why is it that [MOUSE_MOVED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_MOVED) in MouseEvent is considered an int?

Comment: *"find the time since"*  Use a single shot Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Are you sure this is not better suited to a [`JToolTip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)?

Comment: "why is it that MOUSE_MOVED in MouseEvent is considered an int" - its a static final int; that is more commonly known as a constant, a value which does not change at any time. A constant tends to be an integer, but you bind a variable to it (MOUSE_MOVED) to give it a human readable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going backwards through your questions.

> Why is it that MOUSE_MOVED in MouseEvent is considered an int?

All of the mouse constants are ints.  That's how enumeration was done in Java before version 1.5.

> How do I find the time since the mouse last moved?

In your mouseMoved method, you save the current time somewhere in your GUI model.  You then write a method in your GUI model that returns the idle time.

```
idleTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - savedTimeinMillis.
```

You divide the idle time by 1000 for seconds.